# dropdown getting hidden behind view in react native web using react-dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I am using react-dropdown to show a dropdown list but the list is getting hidden behind another view, below is the preview:
[image]

the code for dropdown is as follows:

```
<SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'stretch',
          // justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
        }}>
        <View>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 56,
              backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
              alignItems: 'center',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              zIndex:10,
             
            }}>
            {User != null &&
            User.children != undefined &&
            User.children != null &&
            User.children.length > 0 &&
            mChild != undefined &&
            mChild != null && (
              <Dropdown options={User.children.map((item) => {
                return {
                  label: item.name + '\n' + item.dob_text,
                  value: item,
                  icon: () =>
                    item.pic_url ? (
                      <Image
                        source={{
                          uri: item.pic_url,
                        }}
                        style={{height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 15}}
                      />
                    ) : item.gender === 'male' ? (
                      <Image
                        source={{
                          uri:
                            'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/materia-human/24/013_042_newborn_infant_child_baby-512.png',
                        }}
                        style={{height: 30, width: 30}}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <Image
                        source={{
                          uri:
                            'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/materia-human/24/013_042_newborn_infant_child_baby-512.png',
                        }}
                        style={{height: 30, width: 30}}
                      />
                    ),
                };
              })}
              onChange={(item) => {
                if (item.value.id != mSChildId) {
                  handleChangeChild(item.value.id);
                }
              }} 
              value={defaultchildvalueName}
               placeholder="Select an option" 
              />
            
               
            )}
          </View>          
            
        </View>
        <HomeTabScreen navigation={navigation}/>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Could anyone please help me here?
How do I resolve this?
Any help would be great, let me know for any requirements for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

**try this :** if it works do let me know

```
         <View
            style={{
              height: 56,
              backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
              alignItems: 'center',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',

             // increase the zIndex value something like : zIndex >> 10 to 1000

             zIndex : 1000
            }}>
```

Comment: no, this is not working, had even tried with position:'absolute' but did not work out

Comment: you can try this one ==>> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker